# Add Siri commands to shortcut in iOS 14

Tags: iphone, siri, time, shortcuts-app

I can ask Siri: "What's the time"?

Can I put this in a shortcut, and run it every hour between 8am to 7pm, so that my iPhone will announce time every hour?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have direct Siri commands but you can get the current time and you can also speech to text things, here is a [reddit link](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/9uxmmr/siri_tell_me_the_time/) that seems close to what you want to achieve